# Test-Path Move-Item Problems

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-5.0

I run this PowerShell script, and it works fine on PowerShell 4.0. But I now have PowerShell 5.0 and the script does work but it throws an error:

The Script:

```
$path = "X"
$destination = "Y"

while (Test-Path -Path $path) {
    Move-Item -Path "$path\*zip" -Destination "$destination"
    }
```

The error I get is:

> Move-Item : The process cannot access the file because it is being
>   used by another process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do it

```
 Move-Item -Path "$path\*zip" -Destination "$destination" -ErrorAction Ignore
```

Answer (score 1):

The title of the question: "Test-Path Move-Item Problems" implies that one cmdlet might be impacting the other. That doesn't make sense to me as `Test-Path` is checking the folder's existence and `Move-Item` is working on child items within that folder.

Personally I would **not** use a `while` loop for this use case as, once you have determined that the path exists you don't need to keep testing it:

```
if(Test-Path -Path $path){
  Move-Item -Path $path\*zip -Destination $destination
}
```